# Rmongodb package date object

Tags: mongodb-query, rmongodb

I have a collection in MongoDb and am trying to import the data into R using the rmongodb package. I would like to subset the documents based on the date and time that exists in my database .

So I use the mongo.find.all function defined under the rmongodb package as follows: to try to extract documents that are before a particular date time point.

```
query<-mongo.bson.from.JSON('{"Date_time":{"$lte":"2015-1-5 20:00:00"}}')
sample<-mongo.find.all(mongo,db.coll,query)
```

I  do not get any output at all.

R is considering the date time object as string instead of date variable.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, use `mongo.bson.from.list()` function, which directly converts R's types into MongoDB types.

```
posix_time <- strptime(x = "2015-1-5 20:00:00", format = '%F')
query <- mongo.bson.from.list(list("Date_time" = list("$lte" = posix_time)))
sample <- mongo.find.all(mongo,"db.coll",query)
```

Also `mongo.bson.from.list()` is much faster because it avoids JSON parsing.

P.S. In fact `mongo.bson.from.JSON` uses it under the hood.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Dmitriy. Another thing we noticed that when we import data in R from MongoDB using mongo.find.all or mongo.find.batch function, the original datatypes of fields are not maintained because fields take character values in one or more documents. (e.g. "null"). After importing such fields and converting it into R data frames, it will consider as Character variables. How can we replace these "null" values by NA's and preserve the original data types from MongoDB. These typed feature is already available when we import CSV files using na.strings = "null" argument in read.csv function.

Comment: please, fill issue report and provide reproducible example at https://github.com/mongosoup/rmongodb/issues.

Comment: The issue has been reported with a reproducible example at https://github.com/mongosoup/rmongodb/issues/76. –  user76170